# PHP preg_replace_callback catch more than one occurance in line

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace-callback

I search for custom HTML tags with:

```
$match = preg_replace_callback("/<tag>(.*)<tag>/", function ($key) {
    $result = getTxt($key[1]);

    return $result;
}, $buffer);
```

It works when input is:

```
Abc <tag>1<tag> efg
```

But why it returns `null` on:

```
Abc <tag>2<tag> ef <tag>3<tag> h
```

I've tried to group nongreedy ending tag: `/$tag(.*)($tag?)/` with same result.

Comment: Since when was a (?:X|H)TML tag ever closed by another opening tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the `.*` non greedy via `.*?`

```
/<tag>(.*?)<tag>/
```

Say `$tag` is `<tag>`, that means `$tag?` becomes `<tag>?` which captures `<tag` and `<tag>`